# MsBuild PostBuild targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj, msbuild-target

I have added an `AfterBuild` target to a Visual Studio project, which is part of a solution containing multiple Visual Studio projects.

*Example Solution setup*

Example.sln

- ExampleProj.csproj
- ExampleProj.Test.csproj

*Example of Target:*

```
  <Target Name="PostBuildScript" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <BuildCommand>"SomeApplication.exe")</BuildCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(BuildCommand)" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
```

I would like this target to execute **only** after all of the Visual Studio projects in the solution have been built.

Is there a way to achieve this.

*Note: I need the behaviour to be the same when using `dotnet build` as well as the build command in Visual Studio.*

Comment: What issue are you having with this?

Comment: The target runs tests (amongst other things) and I find that the target sometimes runs before the Test project has built it's assemblies, and so the tests fall. Note: I am only adding the target to the main project so that certain commands only occur once. I am trying to avoid having to add other targets to other projects as then the order of execution of targets across the projects becomes difficult to manage.

Comment: I find the best way to reference projects among each other in a solution is to use project references. That way the projects themselves determine the build order, and not the solution file itself. If I were you, I would attach that post build target on the project that is always built last (If you have one).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I would like this target to execute only after all of the Visual Studio projects in the solution have been built

According to the document [MSBuild Extending The Solution Build](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx), you could create a MSBuild project files named `after.<SolutionName>.sln.targets` in the same folder as your solution.

As test, I added this to my After.Solution.sln.targets file (Use a banana instead of SomeApplication.exe), and set this file in the same folder as my solution file `.sln`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="PostBuildScript" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Message Text="*** BEGIN BANANA ***" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" _                                          " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="//\                                         " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="V  \                                        " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text=" \  \_                                      " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="  \,'.`-.                                   " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="   |\ `. `.                                 " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="   ( \  `. `-.                        _,.-:\" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="    \ \   `.  `-._             __..--' ,-';/" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="     \ `.   `-.   `-..___..---'   _.--' ,'/ " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="      `. `.    `-._        __..--'    ,' /  " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="        `. `-_     ``--..''       _.-' ,'   " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="          `-_ `-.___        __,--'   ,'     " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="             `-.__  `----'''    __.-'       " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="                  `--..____..--'            " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="*** END BANANA ***"  Importance="high" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Then I build it with `dotnet build` command:

```
dotnet build "xxxx\TestSolutionTarget.sln" --configuration Release --verbosity n
```

[image]

This target execute after **all** of the Visual Studio projects in the solution have been built.

**Alternatively**, you could also create separate empty project, referencing subset of all the projects and adding this target to the empty project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Ibz, You are always welcome. SO forum seems to have problems, photos can not be loaded correctly. So I share the test result by onedrive here:https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHf2VjaF3gem2iYWd1X

Comment: While the above works in the command line, I am finding that the `after.<SolutionName>.sln.targets` appears to be ignored by Visual Studio 2017 and the banana does not show in the output. Please help.

Comment: @Ibz, Yes, It seems this target only triggered by command line. In the referenced document, I found that **If you are building solution files from the command then you might be interested in the technique.**. So, if you still want to the banana shows in the Visual Studio output window, you can try to use the second method in my answer: **create separate empty project, referencing subset of all the projects and adding this target to the empty project**.